# How can I use nginx in Windows server to create a loadbalancer?

Tags: ssl, nginx, iis, openssl, devops

I have big really big trouble. I tried many times to start nginx server as windows service after binding 2 websites which are hosted IIS by using kestrel but I couldn't achieve that,It creates below error. How can I solve this problem?I created certs with below codes:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in xyz.com.pfx -nocerts -out /xyzcert/xyz.com.pem
openssl rsa -in /certificate/xyz.pem -out /xyzcert/xyz.com.key
openssl x509 -outform der -in /xyzcert/xyz.com.pem -out 
/xyzcert/xyz.com.crt
```

if I check my error log:

```py
2019/05/31 13:58:14 [emerg] 8792#10088: no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
2019/05/31 13:58:16 [emerg] 7324#8852: no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
2019/05/31 13:58:20 [emerg] 8520#9928: no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
```

Nginx.conf

```py
http {
    #...
    upstream loadbalancer.xyz.com {
        server staging1.xyz.com:996;
        server staging2.xyz.com:997;
   }

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name www.loadbalancer.xyz.com;
        #...

        location /upstream {
            proxy_pass                    https://loadbalancer.xyz.com;
            proxy_ssl_certificate         /xyzcert/xyz.com.crt;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /xyzcert/xyz.com.key;
            proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /xyzcert/xyz.com.pem;

            proxy_ssl_verify        on;
            proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name staging1.xyz.com;

        ssl_certificate        /xyzcert/xyz.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /xyzcert/xyz.com.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /xyzcert/xyz.com.pem;

        location /yourapp {
            proxy_pass http://staging1.xyz.com;
        #...
        }
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name staging2.xyz.com;

        ssl_certificate        /xyzcert/xyz.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /xyzcert/xyz.com.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /xyzcert/xyz.com.pem;

        location /yourapp {
           proxy_pass http://staging2.xyz.com;
        #...
        }
    }
}
```

So it means that I have some certification issue but I studied to solve that issue by creating certs like above. How can I start my loadbalancer by using my config. Or I have a some another issue to manage it.I need your great helps . Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You need to remove `ssl_verify_client      optional;` line, unless you want your clients to authenticate themselves with client certificate.

Comment: @DusanBajic I updated my nginx.conf file. Thank you for your interest

Comment: But can you now try to restart and share updated error log?